# From a list, dynamically create methods with name-awareness

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

I'm trying to write a simple console color utility that takes a class full of ANSI codes and generates some helper methods on my console utility, so that instead of doing `console.add('text', 'blue')`, I can do `console.blue('text')`.

I know I can define all of these statically (e.g. `def blue(self, s):`), but that doesn't really scale well if I want to add 100 or so more helpers (not that I would, but *if...*)

Here's the simple ANSI map:

```
class _AnsiColors:
    def __init__(self):
        self.green = 35
        self.red = 1
        self.blue = 32
        self.yellow = 214
        self.amber = 208
        self.olive = 106
        self.orange = 166
        self.purple = 18
        self.pink = 197
        self.gray = 243
        self.dark_gray = 238
        self.light_gray = 248
        self.black = 0
        self.white = 255
        self.debug = 24

ansi = _AnsiColors()
```

And the console utility (which proxies methods to `pyfancy` and uses `colors`):

```
import copy 

from colors import color    
from pyfancy import *

from ansi import ansi

class console(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self._s = pyfancy(s)

    def add(self, s, c='white'):
        if hasattr(ansi, self.add.__name__):
            c = self.add.__name__
        self._s.add(color(s, fg=getattr(ansi, c)))
        return self

    def bold(self, s):
        self._s.bold(s)
        return self

    def raw(self, s):
        self._s.raw(s)  
        return self

    def dim(self, s):
        self._s.dim(s)      
        return self

    def print(self):
        self._s.output()

# Inject ansi color convenience methods
for c in vars(ansi):
    setattr(console, c, copy.deepcopy(console.add))
    getattr(console, c).__name__ = c
```

Then I can use it like so:

```
console('raw').bold(' bold').raw(' raw').blue(' blue').red(' red').print()
```

You can see that the helper methods `blue` and `red` at least execute, so my copying of `add()` works, but what's happening here (even though I thought I could solve it with `copy.deepcopy`), is that when I try and set the `__name__` property of each method copy, it's setting the reference to `add` instead, and I end up with all of the colored output being the same color (`ansi.debug`).

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do without statically defining each helper?

---

MCVE without colors/pyfancy:

```
import copy 

from ansi import ansi

class console(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self._s = s

    def add(self, s, c='white'):
        if hasattr(ansi, self.add.__name__):
            c = self.add.__name__
        self._s += '%s(%s)' % (s, c)
        return self

    def print(self):
        print(self._s)

# Inject ansi color convenience methods
for c in vars(ansi):
    setattr(console, c, copy.deepcopy(console.add))
    getattr(console, c).__name__ = c

console('white').blue(' blue').red(' red').print()

# white blue(debug) red(debug)
```

Comment: Do you have a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that doesn't involve `pyfancy` and `colors`?

Comment: Sure, added one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it with a closure:

```
class console(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self._s = s
        for color in vars(ansi):
            self._colorizer(color)

    def _colorizer(self, c):        
        def add(s):
            self._s += '%s(%s)' % (s, c)
            return self

        self.__setattr__(c, add)

    def print(self):
        print(self._s)

console('white').blue(' blue').red(' red').print()
# white blue(blue) red(red)
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks. Fwiw, I think you can completely skip the `_add` function and call it directly in the `vars(ansi)` loop. And for my use case, because I'm using `color` globally, I have to rename some of the loop vars and function name so stuff isn't clobbered.

Comment: yes I misunderstood what the add function does and edited accordingly ;-)